# add icon on run time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a gui. I am creating a new form from the original form programatically on a button click.

```
Form frm1 = new Form();
frm1.ShowDialog();
```

I also want to add icon to this form (other than default).
I looked that how main form has added the icon and I found out

```
this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
```

How can I do the same for the new form and in which directory should I place the new icon ? (as its not clear from the auto generated code of the main form which i posted above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options here

1) If you have a file with .ico extension you can load it using Icon's class constructor

```
string pathToIconFile = ...
this.Icon = new Icon(pathToIconFile);
```

2) you can create an icon resource in Properties project folder. When you opened Properties click on Resources.resx and there Add Resource->Add New Icon menu items. This will create an icon. You can also load an icon from an existing file into the resource, in this case the icon will be built in your executable. The difference with option 1 is that you will need not to distribute the icon file with your executable so it could be loaded at runtime(remember of pathToIconFile)
So, when your icon added as a resource it will be given some name. If it's myIconResource you can set your form's icon like this:

```
this.Icon = Properties.Resource.myIconResource;
```